# How can I deploy an AIR application to older iOS hardware (i.e. not using AIR 2.6)?

Tags: ios, air, adt

This is an update of an earlier question which mistakenly assumed that the AIR 2.5 libraries supported iOS.

I am trying to use AIR to package an ipa for the older iOS hardware that AIR 2.6 doesn't support. Adobe's suggestion is to use AIR 2.0.2 for these devices.

However, I seem to be at a bad place in the product lifecycle. The original way to get stuff onto iOS devices using AIR was to use a tool called Packager for Iphone (pfi). That was available as part of the original AIR 2.0 SDK and separately through the Labs website. Now that Adobe has released the new build tools for AIR 2.6, they've taken down the PFI page on Labs, and the archived version of AIR 2.0.2 does not include PFI. Adobe says they have rolled the PFI capabilities into their general-purpose command-line build tool (adt).

So I have tried using the version of adt that is included with AIR 2.6, using a swf that is compiled for Flex 4.1 and Flash Player 10 and specifying 2.0 as the AIR namespace. This produces an iOS package without any errors, but my iPod rejects the app with the same message it uses when I try to give it a 2.6 app : "This application is not compatible with this iPod." So it looks like the newer build tool only wants to build the newer kind of ipa and doesn't respect the specified namespace.

Am I out of luck here or is there still some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Forums helped me out with this one. For the moment at least, it is possible to get PFI (including the PC binary, pfi.exe) here:
http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flash/updates/11/ios/win/PFI_WIN_2_ 0_1_12640.zip

I'm a new user and can't post both links, but the Mac version is also accessible. Same server, different path:
[server]/pub/flash/updates/11/ios/mac/PFI_MAC_2_ 0_1_12640.zip

The Mac version doesn't include a binary, so you call it like this:
java -jar /path/to/PFI/lib/pfi.jar

Substitute that string wherever you see 'pfi' in online tutorials or whatever, like this:
java -jar /path/to/PFI/lib/pfi.jar -package \
-target ipa-test -provisioning-profile /path/to/provision.mobileprovision \
...

source: the helpful people on this thread
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3739613#3739613